# Twitter feed in a regular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

Twitter's embed code is a big clunky if you ask me. It appears you have to load the js and put the js embed code (javascript) in the page where you want it in order for it to show up. I would like to load the js right before the end of my `</body>` and also put the js script in there as well. I would then like to just place an empty div anywhere on my page and the twitter feed will display there. Like `<div id='twitter_feed'></div>` Is that possible adjusting the code that Twitter gives us?

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('example').start();
</script>
```

My question is not how to using different tools to render a feed. My question is how do I make the above code that twitter provides and write it in a way that it will render in a div that I specify.

After reading though this...http://www.dustindiaz.com/twitter-widget-doc I found that you can specify an id.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/) sounds like what you want, using jQuery tweets plugin found on http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-Tweets

HTML

```
<div id="tweets">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 $('#tweets').tweets({
           tweets:4,
           username: "jquery"
  });
```

---

or using your current widget http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/dZ2aP/

```
<div class="content_up_here">
There's so much stuff here.
</div>
<script>twitterwidget();</script>
<div class="content_down_here">
Lorem and Ipsum sitting in a tree. D O L O R S I T.
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code here in addition to the link off site.  If the page you linked to gets taken down for any reason, your answer will become useless.

Comment: @mazlix - that is what I want essentially but I want to use the official twitter code they provided. Is it possible?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Fixed that. ..keith: I'm don't know about widgets.twimg.com, but the jqeury plugin tweets should work ...

Comment: @mazlix - Can't I put the Twitter code in a function or something and then have query tell a certain div to run that function? Is that possible?

Comment: Well actually, I think wherever you put the <script>...</script> is where it your thing will appear... and u can change the id by including an `id: "...."` parameter... I'll update my answer... hope that can help....

Answer (score 0):

```
var username = "username";
$.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/"+username+".json?callback=?",
function(data) {  
  function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
  }

  $("#tweet").html(replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data[0].text));
});
```

The above script will parse links and usernames and make them actual links. All you need to do is have a div with the id of `#tweet`. Make sure you load jQuery too. This also get only one lastest tweet.